# Validation Rule when Lead is converted

Tags: validation-rule, record-type

Hi all I am creating a Validation rule on lead upon conversion when a record type is a customer or partner and the picklist field "Item__c" is blank
I am using the below it is not working can anyone please help me correct this

```
AND(
    RecordTypeName =‘Customer’,'partner',
    IsConverted
    ISBLANK(Item__c)
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/360155/edit) your question to elaborate on what you mean by "it is not working" - for example: give *exact* error text, or tell *exactly* what it is (or is not) doing in relation to what you expect it to do. *(See [this section](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the Help Center.)*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some "smart" quotes in your validation formula (which can cause all sorts of interesting error messages), and your syntax for checking multiple record types is incorrect.

In formulas like this (and in programming in general), you cannot compare one value to two others simultaneously. You need to be explicit, and test them one at a time.

The record type name is also not available on any given record. The field is `RecordTypeId`, and if you want to get at the record type's name you need to use dot notation to traverse the relationship (and drop the 'Id' part of the field name since this is a standard relationship) to get at the "Name" field on the actual "RecordType".

Instead of

`RecordTypeName =‘Customer’,'partner'`

You need to do

```
OR(
    RecordType.Name = 'Customer',
    RecordType.Name = 'Partner'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `Validation rule` having some mistakes in syntex. So please correct it and try as below,

```
AND(
    (RecordType.Name ='Customer' || RecordType.Name = 'partner'),
    IsConverted,
    ISBLANK(Item__c)
)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It worked Thanks

Comment: @Ashok Please accept the answer if it worked. It's will really helpful for the remaining users whom having this doubt in forward days.